# Pamd not mounting ecryptfs disk anymore since upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, pam, ecryptfs

I have encrypted my home disk a long time ago and I configured pam to mount it automatically on login.

However after update to version 1.1.5-3 pam is not mounting the disk anymore.
Here are the logs :

```
PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so
pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user ben
PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so): /usr/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Seems like the pam-ecryptfs library has been removed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ecryptfs-utils 96-1 the file `pam_ecryptfs.so` is installed in `/lib/security` ([click](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/ecryptfs-utils/)) which was changed in ecryptfs-utils 96-2 to `/usr/lib/security` ([click](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/ecryptfs-utils&id=5a6de989e56ee183c60abe998197bf23050ef098)). You might just need to update your system.

Comment: My system is up to date, I'm using ArchLinux. pam-ecryptfs is still located in /lib/security and if I copy it /usr/lib/secrity it works.

Comment: ecryptfs-utils 96-2 is still in testing ([click](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community-testing/i686/ecryptfs-utils/))